# RPM package requires older version of installed dependency.

Tags: dependencies, rpm

I have zlib-1.2.3-27 installed, but the software I'm trying to package requires zlib-1.2.2.

The software I am trying to package are precompiled binaries. Is the only option to build from source myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you need that software badly, get the specfile for zlib-1.2.2 (or any other version not too different from your targeted) and rename the package to `zlib-legacy`, be cautionous about librariries (i.e. probably both packages would provide a `libz.so` shared library). Also you need to supply a one more line to the rpm spec file: `Provides: zlib = 1.2.2`
Install the blob rpm via `rpm -ivh`.
Note: this is not tested.

A quick dirty (wihtout creating a aproper legacy package) and *not* recommended *hack* would be to link `libz.so.1.2.2` to `libz.so` (which is of version 1.2.3). This may or may not work depending on API compatibility. Install the blob rpm via `rpm -ivh --nodeps`.